# cannot access the twitter data, how do i solve this

Tags: python, tweepy

```py
consumer_key = "a1"

consumer_secret = "b1"
access_token = "c1"
access_token_secret = "d1"
authorization = tweepy.OAuthHandler(access_token,access_token_secret)
authorization.set_access_token(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

api = tweepy.API(authorization)

tweet1 = api.user_timeline(screen_name='@elonmusk',
                           count=200,
                           include_rts=False,
                           tweet_mode='extended')
print(tweet1)
```

but, I have been getting this error:

> tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
> 453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product

Can anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 0):

The error message gives you a hint:
`tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden 453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product.`

You need to go to that link to get a higher access level.